# xvfb XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server

Tags: linux, xorg, wine, xvfb

I'm running a Windows application in Linux using wine and xvfb, this combination works most of the time, I can see these errors messages many times (but not all the time) I have googled this errors but I haven't found anything useful, has anyone understand what this means and how to fix it?

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":237"
      after 183 requests (183 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":238"
      after 13 requests (13 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":239"
      after 12 requests (11 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":240"
      after 12 requests (11 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":241"
      after 183 requests (183 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":242"
      after 183 requests (183 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```